# SASS in Emmet not working

Tags: sass, emmet

i have a problem with Emmet in SASS. 
For example i write 'w10' then press tab

- css returns 'width: 10px'
- sass returns just tab.

Any thoughts? 
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You have not provided enough information for us to answer your question. What text editor or Emmet implementation are you using? What OS?

Answer (score 2):

If your using sublime text 2 you have to make sure that when you have your SCSS file open that the file syntax selected in the bottom right corner is selected as css.

Emmet bases all of its shorthand syntax off of that value.

There is a way to always open files using a certain syntax. Go to these menus View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... ->[your syntax choice].

And all future files will be open using your select choice

BUT...that being said there is a sweet sublime plugin that takes care of SCSS sass code hilighting and integrates with Emmet.

Use package control to install

SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTING FOR SASS
Then just use the the previous steps to choose SCSS sass as your syntax of choice.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I already use the SCSS syntax that you describe. Still, no luck. `w10` doesn't return `width: 10px;`, just a `tab` character. I'm using Sublime Text 3 and Emmet.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using [Sass Textmate Bundle](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle) Nathos provides [this](https://github.com/nathos/sass-textmate-bundle/issues/38) answer.

In your Sublime directory, go to the directory "Installed Packages". Rename Sass.sublime-package to Sass.zip. [Using Winrar or RAR for Mac](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm), edit Sass.zip and remove the "Snippet" directory. Save it and rename it back to Sass.sublime-package.

Comment: It is better to include at least a part of the content of the link to your answer. because the link may disappear with time.